# Why is the "overflow: hidden" rule for the root element (div id="app") bad practice in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Why shouldn't web developers in Vue, where most of the elements fall outside the block boundaries, use `overflow: hidden` for `<div id = "app">`?

Comment: Have you got the answer ? i am also looking forward to it

Comment: @Robokishan  It's holivar theme. But my command don't use this practice, because this can lead to errors that are hard to catch.

Comment: @Robokishan We think, that each section-component should be process. What is your team's opinion?

Comment: Do not know more about this. But i have seen in so many react projects that they use overfow: hidden in root as well. don't know exact reason.

can you post the theme ?

Comment: @robokishan I tried